# Codeigniter - Delete without refreshing page

Tags: javascript, ajax, codeigniter

I have a problem with ajax delete in codeigniter. I want to delete without refreshing page

Here is my controller

```
    function delete($id_post='')
    {
    $hapus=$this->home_model->delete($id_post);
                if($hapus){
                echo "true";
                } else {
                echo "error";
      }
    }
```

here is my model:

```
function delete($id_post='')
    { 
    $sql  = "DELETE FROM post WHERE id_post=?";
    return $this->db->query($sql,array($id_post));
}
```

Here is my view and javascript:

```
<?php foreach($news as $data):?>
 <div id="row">
<?php echo $data['news']?>
Post by: <?php echo ['username']?>
<button onClick="return confirm('Sure to delete?')" class="btn-danger btn-xs delete" id="<?php echo $data['id_post']?>">delete</button>
</div>
<?endforeach;?>

    <script languge="javascript" type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){ // added
    $(".delete").click(function(){
        //var id_post = this.id;
        var btn = this;
        e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: "<?php echo base_url()?>delete",
               cache: false,
               data: "id_post="+$(this),
               success: function(reaksi){
                   if (reaksi=="true"){
                       alert('Success delete');
                   } else {
                       alert('failed');
                   }
                }
            });
    return false
    });
   }); // added
</script>
```

When i click delete, ajax not even trigerred. Any answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to write this as a comment, but since i am new here so i dont have the required reputation.

If you have written the code exactly as you posted in your question, I think your ajax request is not even being fired because you are calling `$('.delete').click(...` whereas in your code you have put id of link as 'delete' not class!

Add class delete in delete button and everything should work fine.. :)

**Update:**
or you can call `$('#delete').click(...` instead!

**Update 2:**

There are several problems with your code (i'll comment the problems at the changes)

**Controller Function:**

```
function delete() // you arent supplying any arguments in url of ajax call 
{
    $id_post = $this->input->post('id_post'); // get the post data
    $hapus=$this->home_model->delete($id_post);
    if($hapus){
        echo true;
    } else {
        echo false;
    }
}
```

**Javascript:**

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $(".delete").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); 
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "<?php echo base_url()?>delete",
      cache: false,
      data: {id_post:$(this).attr("id")}, // since, you need to delete post of particular id
      success: function(reaksi) {
         if (reaksi){
            alert("Success");
         } else {
             alert("ERROR");
         }
       }
   });
});
});
```

Comment: Check the update 2 in the answer. Please accept the answer if this works.

Comment: it works great but still need to refresh page if want to see the result

Comment: Aren't you removing the html of that particular post from the list on ajax success? Since you were using some custom function like **$("#row").remove ...** before your latest update, so I assumed you were doing same now too. Use any jquery function like **hide() or fadeOut()...**  in success function to remove that particular post's html :)

Answer (score 0):

Two think you need to change in your code

First in your model return restult

```
function delete($id_post='')
{ 
    $sql  = "DELETE FROM post WHERE id_post=?";
    return $this->db->query($sql,array($id_post));
}
```

Second add return false in your ajax function

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
   $(document).ready(function(){
     $("#delete").click(function(e){
       //alert("Delete?");
         e.preventDefault(); 
         var href = $(this).attr("href");
         var btn = this;

        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: href,
          success: function(reaksi) {
             if (reaksi=="Success"){
                alert('Success')
             } else {
                 alert("ERROR");
             }
             return false;

           }
       }
    });
   return false;

   })
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, now data got deleted and return into blank page with text "Success".

Comment: @Andhika try return false in success part

Comment: can explain more detail where i should to put return false?

Comment: i think its beacuse the controller when i click delete button, it will delete data then return to blank page with "Success" text.

Comment: i trying your code with no luck.. Lets say i delete post with id_post=3, then it start to delete process then return to blank page with text "Success" and url bar turn like this `http://localhost/latihan/home/delete/3`

Comment: href="<?php echo site_url("delete/$data[id_post]")?>"  why you have this in your code just remove this because you are calling ajax so after ajax finishes this href take it to new page. change it to href="javascript:;" or href="#"

Comment: i change my button into like this: `<button onClick="return confirm('Are you sure to delete this post?')" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" id="delete">delete</button>` then where should put the `<?php echo site_url("delete/$data[id_post]")?>` ?